# How to list Azure app service read-only environment variables

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Is there a way to list out the *read-only* app service environment variables for an Azure app service?   I need the built-in variables listed here in the first section:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/reference-app-settings?tabs=kudu%2Cdotnet.  For example, the value of WEBSITE_HOSTNAME or SERVER_PORT

I do *not* need to set custom variables in Configuration => Application Settings.  I need an easy list of all environment variables.

Comment: You can find  the list of Environment variables in KUDU Console of your deployed Application.

Comment: Navigate to `Portal` => `Web App` =>Go to `Advanced Tools` under `Development Tools` => Go => Click on `Environment`. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lclR.png)

Comment: Thank you Harshitha, I followed the menu path and found the variables.   The information was buried inside a lot of nested menus.

Comment: Even you can get the variables by running `printenv` in debugconsole.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aL6gB.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- When we deploy `Azure Web App Service` by default app will be set with read-only Environment Variables.
- We can override the existing `Environment variables` in `Configuration` => `App Settings` section of the deployed Web App.

We can check the environment variables in Azure Portal `KUDU` Console.
Path to open `KUDU` Console

Open ***Azure Portal*** => Select your ***App Service*** => Under ***Development Tools*** select ***Advanced Tools*** => Click on ***Go***

[image]

***Way 1 :***

In ***`KUDU Console`*** Click on **Environment**, list of default and the Variables you created in App settings will be seen.

[image]

***Way 2 :***

In ***`KUDU Console`*** Click on `Debug console` and select `CMD` , run ***`printenv`*** command.

[image]